# esp32 reconnect to loss wifi or disconnected mqtt

Tags: esp32, arduino-esp32

I am using esp32 code where it connects with wifi and sends data over mqtt.But on any MQTT failure,it does not reconnect. We should not need to reboot the device from outside, it should get back online whenever the problem is solved. The machine may restart after a long time when it is needed ,but remember on any failure it should not keep rebooting.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Please add enough code so that we can reproduce the problem. One possibility could be, that you try to connect to the MQTT server in an endless `while`-loop. As an alternative, you may use a `for`-loop with a limited number (say 5 or 10 ) trials and then go to sleep or do something else and let it try after a while.